# How to refresh token in Adal?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, adal

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 5. I am using azure active directory authentication oauth 2.0 implicit flow for Login. After 1 hour my application redirects to login page because i handled this in code as below.

```
 protected handleError(error, continuation: () => Observable<any>) {
        if (error.status == 401) {
            this.appContextService.redirectForLogin();
            //return Observable.throw(error);
        }
        else if (error.url && error.url.toLowerCase().includes(this.loginUrl.toLowerCase())) {
            return Observable.throw((error.error && error.error.errormessage) ? `session expired (${error.error.errormessage})` : 'session expired');
        }
        else {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        }
    }

  redirectForLogin() {
        this.loginRedirectUrl = this.router.url;
        this.router.navigate(['']);
        this.adalSvc.login();
    }
```

After one hour i want user not to enter password again. I want to implement refresh token mechanism here. Can someone help me to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Use ADAL.JS :) It handles getting new tokens with hidden iframes.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Adal 5. If i keep web page idle for 1 hr then if i click on some menu it is redirecting me to login screen where i can enter username and password. After the one hour also it should not ask me username and password if the refresh token mechanism is handled properly. Please correct me if i am  wrong.

Comment: Yeah. Which indicates that there is probably a problem in your logic. If you acquire a token from ADAL.JS, it would either give you one from cache or acquire one with an iframe. There is no refresh token though! It relies on the fact that the user has an active session with AAD. The hidden iframe goes to the authorization endpoint and returns an access token assuming the user is still logged in.

Comment: As i am using explicit flow so there is no refresh token. in case of 401 status code, i am redirecting to login screen. I can see there is adal.aquiretoken method. I have not used it. May I know where i should use this?

Comment: Hmm.. I have only tried ADAL.js with Angular 1. But there a 401 would basically never happen. Since the ADAL request interceptor would add a valid access token to the request always, and get a new one if necessary. So in that sense, if you still get a 401, redirecting to log in would be the correct thing to do. You should probably look at the logs generated by ADAL. You can find how to enable the logging in the readme: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js